# Facebook Messenger - message status different on app and web

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am curious - I sent two messages to a friend several weeks ago. Never heard back. Checked my phone and it showed the "not delivered" icons. Later was on the web interface and it had "delivered" icons. Checked the app again and still "not delivered".

A week has gone by and the status on the app and web still do not agree. I have tried clearing my cookies and local storage for the web and even uninstalled/reinstalled the app on my phone. Still no difference.

Which is right?

[image: App vs. Web message statuses]

Comment: this is rough... the help instructions for desktop/mobile show the exact same  list of statuses. I also tested and verified that I can see all three statuses in desktop, and that they show the same in mobile. just in case this is relevant: does the friend you're messaging have mobile messenger themselves?

Answer (score 1):

A message goes through 3 different stages:

1. **Sent** (what your iPhone is showing)
2. **Received** (what the web is showing)
3. **Seen** (shows your contact’s face)

The correct message status is the one that is “most advanced,” since it wouldn’t have gotten there without going through earlier stages. Any device that shows an earlier stage may have suffered from a communications/server error at the time Facebook tried to notify it of the message’s status.

Comment: Thanks @phong. But why when uninstalling and then reinstalling my app does the "most advanced" stage (in this case "Received") not get pulled from the database. I can't help but think there must be a source of truth for new app installs to pull from.

Comment: You make a good point, and I don’t really have a good explanation for that.